# Unirest.delete() blocks any further Unirest method, when response.body is empty

Tags: java, unirest

We use Unirest 1.5.4 for java. Our server responses on DELETE calls with a 204 - NO_CONTENT status and an empty response body.
When I do synchronous delete call the following calls will end in an SocketTimeoutException.

For deeper investigation I swapped some lines in the server to respond status 200 and a "{}" body. Only with this server-side hack Unirest works fine.

here is my (failing) Unirest client code:

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws UnirestException {
    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9010/orga/";
    String orgaJson = "{}";
    HttpResponse<String> postResponse = Unirest.post(baseUrl).body(orgaJson).asString();
    System.out.println("POST status = " + postResponse.getStatus());
    JSONObject orga = new JSONObject(postResponse.getBody());
    String orgaId = orga.getJSONObject("_id").getString("$oid");
    HttpResponse<String> deleteResponse = Unirest.delete(baseUrl+"{id}").routeParam("id", orgaId).asString();
    System.out.println("DELETE status = " + deleteResponse.getStatus());
    System.out.println("DELETE body = " + deleteResponse.getBody());
    // the next call will cause a SocketTimeoutException
    Unirest.post(baseUrl).body(orgaJson).asString();
}
```

Comment: BTW, if it makes a difference to anyone, I think the OP meant version 1.4.5, not 1.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar problem by setting timeouts slightly higher than the defaults. It looks like if you try to make multiple connections to a service like MailChimp every subsequent request takes a little more time. Try experimenting with it a bit.

```
Unirest.setTimeouts(10000, 30000);
```